# Move to eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Now that the new version of eclipse is out should I move to immediately? If my plug-ins work in Galileo will it work in the indigo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to know without trying or researching what the particular plugin providers state regarding Indigo compatibility. Many plugins will work just fine. Some will not.

I would recommend starting a separate Indigo install along side your working Galileo install. Then install your plugins into the new install one by one. If everything installs and appears to be working, you can safely transition. If it doesn't, you will know which plugins are incompatible. Maybe a newer version exists or is on the way.

Comment: Indigo even have a new import wizard that will make your life much easier: `Import->Install->Existing Installation` (or something close). This wizard will try to install plug-ins from an "old" Eclipse installation into the current installation.

Comment: +1 for the separate install suggestion. Keeping my old install saved me a lot of pain, since I've had way too many issues with Indigo for it to be usable at this point. Worst thing? I never even *got* to installing my non-default plugins...

Answer (score 1):

I am planning not to switch before SR2 is available. In the past new Eclipse versions had some minor bugs and I don't see the big advantage of Indigo for my daily work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a risk worth taking. First, create a copy of your eclipse installation and upgrade and see if your plugins are working fine.

If those are working it's good to go Indigo.

All the best with Indigo.